# PHP Pagerank Class

Tags: pagerank

I have a [AMPPS Stack](http://www.ampps.com) for Mac and I am trying to make a PageRank webtool which will allow to show the PageRank of any site.

I have the following Class :
https://raw.github.com/phurix/pagerank/master/pagerank.class.php

When I use this code :

```
include(pagerank.class.php);

$rank = new PageRank('http://www.mysite.com');
print_r($rank);
```

It returns an Object which looks like this in print_r() :
PageRank Object ( [host] => toolbarqueries.google.com )

As per the code it should give the returned output right ?

Comment: BTW the pagerank is on page, not the whole website.

Comment: Hi, what is the function you ended up using?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return information from the object constructor. There's a `return` statement in the constructor (it returns `file_get_contents(something)`) which will get ignored.

Use a function instead.

Comment: Thanks for the information.
I have used the Function instead and it works now.